# Leaflet - Angular : Best way to display a big matrix of data as a grid

Tags: angular, matrix, leaflet

I need to display a matrix of data (numbers), that I get from an external API, as a grid in a Leaflet Map. Every number of my matrix represents a physical measurement in a given zone. Depending on the value of the data, it should be represented by a different color (example : red for a high number, green for a low). You can see a representation of my need :

[image]

I have already implemented a solution that uses Leaflet's Rectangle. So, for every number of my matrix I create a Rectangle defined by its coordinates and a color. All rectangles are then added in my map.

Basically, my code could be summarized by the following lines :

```
var matrix=getDataFromAPI();
var layerGroup=L.LayerGroup;

//works well
for(var i=0 ; i<matrix.height ; i++)
{
   for(var j=0 ; j<matrix.width ; j++)
   {
      layerGroup.addLayer(L.Rectangle(matrix[i][j].coordinates,{fillcolor: getColor(matrix[i][j].value)}));
   }
}

//Work with a small matrix - Doesn't work with a big matrix
map.addLayer(layerGroup);
```

This solution work very well for a small matrix (5*5 for example), but when I need to display a bigger matrix (400*400) my app become unusable. All my rectangles are created (almost fastly) but when I add the layerGroup in the map my app doesn't respond anymore.

So I came to the conclusion that creating a Rectangle for every element of my matrix is not the good solution for my need. Despite my search I didn't find a better solution to do it.
Solutions I found are :

- Create an image representing my data and display it
- Create an entire GeoServer

Those 2 solutions are not suitable for me. The first one because the user will have to interact with every case of my grid and the second one for the same reason and also because I'm absolutely not capable to produce an entire GeoServer.

The best way for me should be to use the implementation I made in an optimized way.

I thank you for all your responses.

Comment: `L.ImageOverlay`s can be interacted with, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29495702/getting-pixel-coordinates-of-an-image-overlay-using-leaflet-map-library-on-click

Comment: So I should create an image that represents my data and display the image, is there not an efficient way to work with any kind of object ?